# How to get TortoiseSVN 1.7.x revision programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to get current revision number of TortoiseSVN 1.7 local working copy programmatically?
I want to use it to set version of my software installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Tortoise is nothing else the UI client for [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) project.

There is a guide for automatton of Tortoise client from command line: [Automating Tortoise from command line](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

If it's not enough, just install any Subversion client available on internet, for example: 
[SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download), or just original one and

1. Move to working copy directory
2. After run from command line `svn info --xml > log.xml`. You will all information you need in XML format in `log.xml`.

   Or

   Just run `svn info $WorkingCopyPath$ --xml > log.xml`

Hope this helps

Comment: The last versions of Tortoise include a checkbox in the installer to also install the command line version of svn at the same time, really useful.

Answer (score 4):

## Don't reinvent the wheel!

Instead of dealing with svnversion or svn info and parsing results, you have with TSVN [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) command-line tool, which allow to use (versioned) template file, in which some changeable repository-related  data is defined as [SubWCRev-keywords](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html) and your build-tool (or you, by hand) just have to run SubWCRev with needed template-file on your WC and get  versioninfo for installer in result-file

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN comes with the command-line tool `svnversion.exe`. 
This tiny little tool just prints out the revision number of a local working copy.
If you don't specify a working copy directory it checks the current directory if it is a working copy (if not it outputs "exported") and if yes it prints out th revision number and the flag(s) - e.g. `M` for *modified*.

Answer (score 1):

You can get svn info by using console tool *SubWCRev.exe* directry: (Use Subversion Revision Numbers in your Visual Studio Projects)[http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/svn_visual_studio.aspx].

Another way to get svn info is to use special msbuild task avaliable in (MSBuild Community Tasks)[http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/]. For example, you can update your AssemlyInfo files with fresh data every time you build your project. Check out this article: [Insert SVN version and Build number in your C# AssemblyInfo file](http://florent.clairambault.fr/insert-svn-version-and-build-number-in-your-c-assemblyinfo-file).

For example, later you can embed your AssemblyInfo data into wix project [How to insert an assembly version number into a WiX script at build time](http://andrewwhitten.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/how-to-insert-an-assembly-version-number-into-a-wix-script-at-build-time/).

Answer (score 1):

After some research, this was the easiest way for me:

1. Within C#, run SubWCRev.exe (which is installed with Tortoise SVN)
2. Read the revision number form its output

1st part: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/07/running-an-executable-and-collecting-the-output.aspx

2nd part:

```
string exe = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe";
string projectPath = @"C:\MyProject";
RunResults runResults = Program.RunExecutable(exe, projectPath, projectPath);
string lines = runResults.Output.ToString();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\D*Updated to revision ([0-9]+)\D*");

Match match = regex.Match(lines);
int revision = -1;
if (match.Success)
{
    revision = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

No idea if this is the best solution. For me, it was the least complicated. I had tried  http://netpl.blogspot.de/2011/10/reading-revision-number-of-local-copy.html which did not work. The svn Version is not included in my Sqlite Database and therefore can't be read from any of the regex proposed on the article.